# fix decapitalization in biblatex/biber when using the related field

Tags: biblatex, biber

The following code uses the related field correctly, but the title taken from the related bib-item is not decapitalized as it is done with the original title.

[image]

I guess this is related to the langsci datamodel files, but I have no clue where to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Montague73a,
        author = {Richard Montague},
        checked = {stmue 2021},
        crossref = {HMS73a-ed},
        pages = {221--242},
        related = {Montague74b-u},
        relatedstring = {Reprint as},
        title = {The Proper Treatment of Quantification in Ordinary {English}}}


@book{HMS73a-ed,
        address = {Dordrecht},
        booktitle = {Approaches to Natural Language. {Proceedings} of the 1970 {Stanford Workshop on Grammar and Semantics}},
        editor = {Jaakko Hintikka and Julian Moravcsik and Patrick Suppes},
        number = {49},
        publisher = {Reidel},
        series = {Synthese Library},
        title = {Approaches to Natural Language. {Proceedings} of the 1970 {Stanford Workshop on Grammar and Semantics}},
        year = 1973}


@incollection{Montague74b-u,
        author = {Richard Montague},
        crossref = {Montague74a-ed},
        pages = {247--270},
        title = {The Proper Treatment of Quantification in Ordinary {English}}}



@book{Montague74a-ed,
        address = {New Haven, CT},
        author = {Richard Montague},
        booktitle = {Formal Philosophy: {Selected} Papers of {Richard Montague}},
        editor = {Richmond H. Thomason},
        ids = {Montague1974},
        publisher = {Yale University Press},
        title = {Formal Philosophy: {Selected} Papers of {Richard Montague}},
        year = {1974}}




\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
        natbib=true,
        style=langsci-unified,
        citestyle=langsci-unified,
        datamodel=langsci,   % add authauthor and autheditor as possible fields to bibtex entries
        backend=biber,
        indexing=cite,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lsDOIGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.45}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Montague73a}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

This issue was fixed in  `biblatex` 3.17.

---

This is a bug in the `biblatex` standard styles that was reported about a week ago. It will be fixed in the upcoming release. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1149 (and https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/issues/22) for details.

If you need a solution now, the following MWE contains the fixed definition of `related:default` that will be in `biblatex` v3.17. Remember to delete this code block when you update, so you can benefit from future improvements to that macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=langsci-unified,
  datamodel=langsci,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% fix for https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1149
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600943/35864
% remove this when biblatex is updated to v3.17
\renewbibmacro*{related:default}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\ifnameundef{savedauthor}
         {\ifnameundef{savededitor}
            {}
            {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}
               {\clearname{editor}}
               {}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}
            {\clearname{author}}
            {}}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
       % from authortitle and authoryear
       \ifbibmacroundef{bbx:dashcheck}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{##2}}%
       % authoryear
       \ifbibmacroundef{labeltitle}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{labeltitle}{}}%
       \ifbibmacroundef{date+extradate}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{}%
          \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}%
       \renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Montague73a,
  author        = {Richard Montague},
  checked       = {stmue 2021},
  crossref      = {HMS73a-ed},
  pages         = {221--242},
  related       = {Montague74b-u},
  relatedstring = {Reprint as},
  title         = {The Proper Treatment of Quantification in Ordinary {English}},
}
@proceedings{HMS73a-ed,
  address    = {Dordrecht},
  editor     = {Jaakko Hintikka and Julian Moravcsik and Patrick Suppes},
  number     = {49},
  publisher  = {Reidel},
  series     = {Synthese Library},
  title      = {Approaches to Natural Language},
  titleaddon = {Proceedings of the 1970 {Stanford Workshop on Grammar and Semantics}},
  year       = 1973,
}
@incollection{Montague74b-u,
  author   = {Richard Montague},
  crossref = {Montague74a-ed},
  pages    = {247--270},
  title    = {The Proper Treatment of Quantification in Ordinary {English}},
}
@book{Montague74a-ed,
  address   = {New Haven, CT},
  author    = {Richard Montague},
  editor    = {Richmond H. Thomason},
  ids       = {Montague1974},
  publisher = {Yale University Press},
  title     = {Formal Philosophy: {Selected} Papers of {Richard Montague}},
  year      = {1974},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{Montague73a}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Montague, Richard. 1973. The proper treatment of quantification in ordinary English. In Jaakko Hintikka, Julian Moravcsik & Patrick Suppes (eds.), Approaches to natural language. Proceedings of the 1970 Stanford Workshop on Grammar and Semantics (Synthese Library 49), 221–242. Dordrecht: Reidel. Reprint as The proper treatment of quantification in ordinary English. In Richmond H. Thomason (ed.), 247–270. New Haven, CT: Yale University Press, 1974.]

- Note that `style=langsci-unified, citestyle=langsci-unified,` is equivalent to `style=langsci-unified,`, since `style=<style>` just sets `bibstyle=<style>` and `citestyle=<style>`.
- `@book`s don't have a `booktitle`, they only have a `title`. With `backend=bibtex,` you had to include a copy of `title` as `booktitle` for the crossref feature, but with `biblatex` this is no longer necessary.
- From the title `HMS73a-ed` sounds like it would be a `@proceedings` (at the very least it is a `@collection` because it has no author and `@book`s usually have authors, plus the child entry `HMS73a-ed` is already an `@incollection`). If `HMS73a-ed` is changed to `@proceedings`, `Montague73a` should be `@inproceedings`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know about the booktitle issue, but my interface does not inherit the title from books to incollection. For this reason and to stay compatible with old bibtex stuff, I decided to do it the old way. The proceedings/collection/book issue is not always easy to decide. Sometimes proceedigns have series and number and so on and are part of a general book series. In these cases I assigned the books to @book. Maybe this is wrong ...

Comment: @StefanMüller A `@proceedings` can have a `series` and `number` too, so that is no reason to favour `@book`. In this case the title contained "Proceedings of the ...", which seems a good enough reason to switch to `@proceedings` to me. (And as mentioned above a `@book` will usually have authors who jointly authored the complete work, which does not appear to be the case here.)